# PostgreSQL ensure no concurrent reads

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I'm sorry if it's a very basic question, but would really appreciate educated advice on this:

Say I have an operation, which first has to read from a table and then insert a row if the read value satisfies a certain condition, and throw if it doesn't, e.g. I have a following table:

```
id     | value
---------------
serial | integer
```

And before inserting a row I need to first:

```
select sum(value) from table;
```

then if `sum` + `value` of the row, which I wanna insert is less than 100 - insert, if no - throw.

I need to somehow make those reads be processed only one-by-one, because if I have 2 concurrent queries, both would read, get that the sum is less than 100 and both insert, which would result in an undesired state, which would have been avoided if queries were executed sequentially.

What would be optimal solution to ensure one-by-one processing here?

So far I've tried doing `select for update` to lock concurrent read operations, but I have a feeling it might be not optimal here...

I'm also aware I could do that with a before insert trigger but the nature of this logic seems not to fit there because the threshold (`100` in the example) comes from application layer runtime and is actually different every time.

I've read a bit about transaction modes (e.g. serializable) but not sure if that's what I need here...

Comment: If you aren't worried about concurrency (or lack there of) using a serialisable transaction will definitely do it for you.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone ideally, I'd like it to be as little of a bottleneck as possible, ideally would prefer it to allow concurrency, but not sure if that's possible given such requirements... can you provide an example of using a serialisable tx for it?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to somehow make those reads be processed only one-by-one,
>   because if I have 2 concurrent queries, both would read, get that the
>   sum is less than 100 and both insert, which would result in an
>   undesired state, which would have been avoided if queries were
>   executed sequentially.

That's a typical use case for the serializable isolation level, with an automated retry of the transaction when it fails with a serialization failure (SQLSTATE=40001)

Short of adapting your schema specifically to deal with the concurrency issue, the other techniques you mention are not going to work directly anyway:

- the BEFORE INSERT trigger is limited in visibility to the already committed transactions, so `sum(value) <= 100-newvalue` may be true even  though another transaction has already inserted a row that will make this untrue as soon as it commits.
- In the `select for update` technique, what row(s) is it supposed to lock? Even if doing `select for update` on the entire table, that does not prevent reads or new inserts. The `select for update` technique would work if it targeted a single pre-existing row, that the transaction would need to lock before proceeding further, implementing effectively a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).
  But that table/row does not exist in your schema as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you mind providing an example of using a serializable tx? Also, do you see some possible ways to improve the schema to deal with concurrency here?

Comment: @TristanTzara: many examples here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI. Also I've found https://drkp.net/papers/ssi-vldb12.pdf to be an excellent overview of the feature in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I was more about ensuring consistency here using a serializable transaction, not critical section reference in general...

Comment: I was thinking to do smth like
`begin transaction isolation level serializable;insert into my_table (value) select 10 where (select sum(value) from my_table) < 100 returning id; commit;`
this way I'd get `null` when nothing was inserted and the id if something was inserted. But I have a feeling it's dirty...